# can't get server response when using dropzone.js version 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js version 4 to upload files from a webpage to my server.
The upload works fine, but I'm trying to get the server response.
I'm creating the DZ programmatically.

```
  // create dropzone
        var dz='    <form action="../home/cgi/newFileUpload.exe" ';
        dz+='         class="dropzone"';            
        dz+='         id="my-awesome-dropzone">';
        dz+='         <input type="hidden" name="token" value="token2send"';
        dz+='   </form>';   

    $("#myDZ").prepend(dz);  // there is a DIV called myDZ

  setTimeout(function(){            
         // init dynamic dropzone
       myAwesomeDropzone=$("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone();

            // configure
                    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone  = {
                        init: function() {
                            this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                                 // this should be response from server
                                 alert(responseText);
                            });
                          }
                    };               


    },1000);
```

when I run the code, there is no "alert" at all, but the file uploads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I got to work:

```
  // create dropzone
        var dz='    <form action="../home/cgi/newFileUpload.exe" ';
        dz+='         class="dropzone"';            
        dz+='         id="my-dropzone">';
        dz+='         <input type="hidden" name="token" value="'+tkn+'"';
        dz+='   </form>';   

        $("#myDZ").prepend(dz);

      setTimeout(function(){            
           Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

           // init dynamic dropzone
           var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone");

           // file api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
           myDropzone.on("success",function(file,r){
                // r is server response
                 alert(file.name+" "+r);
           });

      },500);
```